# Every time having to install any package or dist-upgrade, I get dependency error!

Tags: server, apt, dependencies, linux-headers

My setup:

```
Operating system    Ubuntu Linux 16.04.1
Linux 4.4.0-62-generic on x86_64

root@myserv1:~# sudo apt-get -f install fail2ban
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-headers-4.4.0-62-generic : Depends: linux-headers-4.4.0-62 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Any command with `apt-get` that I have tried, has given this error!

Answer (score 3):

Most likely this is an error with the package lists.

Try running:

```
apt-get update
```

Followed by

```
apt-get -f install
```

And

```
apt-get upgrade
```

If this doesn't fix the issue, please post the output of these commands and the contents of the file: `/etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: I'm not believing, it worked !!! I had tried all sorts of things except apt-get -f install !!! The package manager apt-get went back to work, thank you very much :-) --Where do I mark up as resolved?

Comment: @Iori Sanch Mark the answer as correct (answer, not the question).

Answer (score 1):

Before attempting any `apt` tweak, it would be wise if you run `apt-get -f install` command that `apt` suggested you:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

You can now pray to god hoping above command running properly, since I doubt those command will really fix the problem (in most case it didn't).

If it does not work, try `-f` command will bit different arguments:

```
sudo apt-get -f install linux-headers-4.4.0-62-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-62
```

Report back any error messages.